# PHP skip through file under certain conditions

Tags: php

Here's an example of my situation:

```
<?php
if(//condition)
{
   //start output buffer
}
else
{
   //skip through file until POINT A
}
?>
<!-- some nice html, no php here -->
<?php
  //close output buffer & write it to a file
  //POINT A << SKIP TO HERE
?>
```

Basically, I'm loading the HTML code after the PHP code block into an output buffer. My conditional checks if the file that the output buffer writes to exists. If it exists, I just want to skip past the HTML and the output buffer writing, and start off at `POINT A`. I would do an `exit;` but I have more code I wish to output after `POINT A`.

Any help?

Comment: What PHP version do you want to use?

Comment: Couldn't you just enclose the html within a php string?

Comment: @Alin PHP5, @Adam I could, but I can never get HEREDOC to work for me.

Comment: @Sennheiser 5.what? It's important.

Comment: If you were to use PHP5.3 you could use `goto POINT_A;` in your else tree. And then mark the jump point with `POINT_A:` at the start of the line.

Comment: There's absolutely no need for a `goto` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Enclose the code in conditional blocks.
2. If doing 1. gives a too complicated structure consider using flags. `$doPrintSectionA = false;` And checking that flag before you print some section.
3. If you have PHP >= 5.3 you can use the [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) statement.

Note that opening and closing PHP tags doesn't affect the control structures. Ex.:

```
<?php
if(rand(0,1)){
?>

<b>Hello World!</b>

<?php
}
?>
```

And a final warning:

[image]

Comment: @Sennheiser I'd really recommend you don't. All you want to do is execute a certain bit of code if some condition is true, else do nothing. So just put all your code you want to execute if the condition is true inside the `if` block and leave out the `else`. That does exactly what you want and is much much more comprehensible. You'll understand what I mean when you look at your code again one month down the road.

Comment: @bazmegakapa + 1 Randall Munroe. If you want to vote the answer do it for the content. @deceze Agreed. He should keep your code as clean as possible. And `goto`s are usually quick fixes. @Sennheiser Consider using the second option (with the flag) as well if you find the first one too hard.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru I would not have upvoted if I was not satisfied with the content :).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(//condition)
{
   //start output buffer
}
else
{
   //skip through file until POINT A
?>
<!-- some nice html, no php here -->
<?php
  //close output buffer & write it to a file
<?php } ?>
  //POINT A << SKIP TO HERE
?>
```

Comment: You got it backwards. But it seems votes are not affected by answer quality, so you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/* condition */) {
    //start output buffer
    <!-- some nice html, no php here -->
    //close output buffer & write it to a file
}
```

You might also want to organize your code into functions, possibly separate files and possibly even classes.

---

Actually though, if all you're doing is output **static HTML** into a file, you can skip the whole output-buffer-file-writing procedure and just create a separate static HTML file, full stop. Possibly use `include 'file.html'` if you want to show it on this page as well.

Comment: @keith Since this is very much pseudo-code to begin with I'll let the OP fill those in.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can "goto a:" in the script if you're using PHP 5.3 - http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Use goto's and huge if statements though, and you'll end up with some pretty gnarly code. Here's what I would suggest for a start.

```
<?php
if(//condition)
{
   //start output buffer
   include "content/page.html";
  //close output buffer & write it to a file
}

//POINT A 
?>
```